# ¿Como puedo obtener la localizacion del usuario cada segundo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android donde quiero obtener la ubicación lo más rápido posible (cada segundo estaría bien).

Por ahora he añadido los servicios de google play de localización como he visto en muchos tutoriales y consigo obtener la localización correcta del dispositivo.

El problema es que en el código:

```
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
locationRequest.setPriority(500);
```

parece que no hace nada porque obtengo los updates de la localización cada 10-15 segundos.

Añado todo el código:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    public final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
    public final long UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 1;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;

    TextView velocidad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        velocidad = findViewById(R.id.velocidad);

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0f);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
        };
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // New location has now been determined
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) + " Velocidad: "+location.hasSpeed();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

El problema es el tiempo de actualización que me da las ubicaciones cada 10-15 segundos en vez de cada segundo y no consigo que el tiempo baje, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi experiencia cuando estableces la distancia minima de dsplazamiento:

```
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0f);
```

Esta toma prioridad sobre el tiempo:

```
locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

Intenta remover

```
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0f);
```

Comment: He probado a hacer lo que comentas y no ha variado el tiempo, sigue tardando mucho mas que el intervalo establecido

Answer (score 1):

Al definir el intervalo de tiempo entre cada petición, si deseas realizarlo cada segundo, definirias este valor en milisegundos, sería:

```
UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000; //1 segundo
locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
 //locationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILL ISECONDS);
```

Pero esto no es recomendable ya que principalmente se tendrá un alto consumo de la batería.

Comment: He probado a hacer lo que comentas y no ha variado el tiempo, sigue tardando mucho mas de 1 segundo, no se si estaré haciendo algo mas mal o hay otra maneras de obtener la ubicación actual mas rápidas